# Añadir array en lista predefinida

Tags: javascript

Necessito añadir un Array en la siguiente lista de objetos pero no me acaba de funcionar bien. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
var grauMultimedia = {
  num_assignatures : 50,
  assignatures: Array [num_assignatures.length] = {
        nom : "Matematiques",
        crèdits : 50,
        mitjanaNotes : 7.2,
      alumnes : Array [50] = {
          nom : "Jose",
          edat : 18, 
          genere : "Home",
          nota : 7.5,
      },
    },
 };

console.log(grauMultimedia)
```

El nombre de la lista es "grauMultimedia". Ahi me tiene que saltar a un listado de 50 assignaturas, con sus respectivos nombres y luego en "alumnos" tiene que saltarme otro array de 50 alumnos. No es si tengo el codigo correctamente defindio.

Tengo que transformar esto a codigo javascript:

```
var
    
    grauMultimedia : tupla
         num_assignatures: enter;
         assignatures: taula[num_assignatures] de tupla
               nom: cadena;
               crèdits: enter;
               mitjanaNotes: real;
         alumnes: taula[50] de tupla
               nom: cadena;
               edat: enter; 
               genere: caràcter;
               nota: real;
             ftupla
        ftupla
    ftupla
    
fvar
```

Gracias

Comment: Trabajar con arreglos fijos es un poco mas difícil, para solucionar esto te recomiendo utilizar classes o prototypes para manejar los arreglos mas fácilmente

Comment: No hay forma de arreglar eso? Tengo un codigo en lenguaje "pseucodigo" que lo he de transformar a lenguaje "javascript".

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencione en el comentario anteriormente, recomendaba el uso de clases para poder trabajar con arreglos fijos de manera mas fácil.

La ventaja de esto es que puedes definir metodos para poder trabajar mas facilmente con los arreglos y declararlos y poblarlos de manera mas facil,

La desventaja es te tendras que regir a la estructura de la clase y no tendras tanta flexibilidad al crear los objetos, aunque en el ejemplo de mas abajo, deje a los alumnos como objetos anonimos en caso de que quieras agregar los datos que desees.

```
class Assignature {
    constructor(nom, credits, mitjanaNotes, alumnes = []) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.credits = credits;
        this.mitjanaNotes = mitjanaNotes;
        this.alumnes = new Array(50);
        this.AddAlumne = (alumne) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.alumnes.length; i++) {
                const element = this.alumnes[i];
                if (!element) {
                    this.alumnes[i] = alumne;
                    return this;
                }
            }
        };

        alumnes.forEach((element, index) => {
            this.alumnes[index] = element;
        });
    }
}

class GrauMultimedia {
    constructor(num_assignatures, assignatures = []) {
        this.num_assignatures = num_assignatures;
        this.assignatures = new Array(num_assignatures);
        this.AddAssignature = (assignature) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.assignatures.length; i++) {
                const element = this.assignatures[i];
                if (!element) {
                    this.assignatures[i] = assignature;
                    return this;
                }
            }
        };

        assignatures.forEach((element, index) => {
            this.assignatures[index] = element;
        });
    }
}

//Con esto declaras por primera vez los datos
var grauMultimedia = new GrauMultimedia(50, [
    new Assignature('Matematiques', 50, 7.2, [
        {
            nom: 'Jose',
            edat: 18,
            genere: 'Home',
            nota: 7.5,
        },
    ]),
]);

//Agregar una nueva asignatura despues de haber creado el objeto
grauMultimedia.AddAssignature(
    new Assignature('Lenguas', 30, 7.2, [
        {
            nom: 'Jose',
            edat: 18,
            genere: 'Home',
            nota: 7.5,
        },
        {
            nom: 'Pedro',
            edat: 20,
            genere: 'Mujer',
            nota: 7.5,
        },
    ])
);
```

Puedes personalizar la clase a tu gusto, puedes agregar mas métodos para eliminar asignatura o mostrar estadísticas por ejemplo, eso queda a tu criterio.